# JavaScript merge canvas and video context

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a Video tag and above that tag a canvas element in which I can draw. I Need to create a function which does a screenshot of the Video and the canvas.

So far I can create a screenshot of the Video but not both together

My Code so far:

```
getCameraImage () {
    let video = $("video").get(0);
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    let img = document.createElement("img");

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();

    return img.src;
},
```

and this is how I generate img tags with the source:

```
    let screenImg = this.getCameraImage();

    this.screenshotContainer.prepend(
            '<img src="" id=\"current-video-screenshot-' + counter + '\" alt="screenshot" width="300px"/>'
        );
    document.getElementById('current-video-screenshot-'+counter).setAttribute('src', screenImg);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?